# No se almacena correctamente una contraseña hasheada en PHP7

Tags: funciones, php7, hash, contraseña, null

tengo una duda con `php7.3` y la función `password_hash`. Tengo dos ficheros, uno llamado funciones.php donde tengo la función que recibe, valida la contraseña, y devuelve el hash, y en el otro, llamado registro.php donde llamo a la función que devuelve el hash.

Código de la función:

```
/**
 * @return bool|string
 * @throws Exception
 */
function validaYCifraPass(){
    if (isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['pass2'])){
            if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_\-]+$/i',$_POST['pass']) === 1) {
                $contrasena = (string) $_POST['pass'];
                $contrasena2 = (string) $_POST['pass2'];
                if ($contrasena === $contrasena2 && strlen($contrasena) <= 8) {
                    //Validada la contraseña del usuario, llega el momento de cifrarla
                    $coste = ['coste' => 18]; //Aumentamos el coste del algoritmo
                    $passhash = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $coste);
                    return $passhash;
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("La contraseña no es válida");

            }
        }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Debes introducir la contraseña");
    }

}
```

Código de registro.php:

```
    <?php
include 'funciones.php';
try {
    $nombre = validaNombre();
    $passcifrada = validaYCifraPass();
    var_dump($passcifrada); //Devuelve nulo
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die("<a href='../registro.html'>Vuelve al registro</a>");
}
```

Resultado del vardump de la contraseña:

> /srv/http/Mantis-rebirth/scripts/registro.php:6:null

La contraseña debe ser de 8 caracteres o más. 123456789 es la que he usado para meter las contraseñas

Comment: Si dices que la contraseña debe tener 8 caracteres o mas, porque aqui tienes `strlen($contrasena) <= 8` ?? no deberia ser: `strlen($contrasena) >= 8` ?

Comment: Sí, **debería** pero me he confundido

Comment: Esa es la solución

Comment: Me alegro que haya funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la comparación del tamaño de la password con el ejemplo que estas poniendo:

Si pones--> `if ($contrasena === $contrasena2 && strlen($contrasena) <= 8)` e introduces como ejemplo `123456789` no te va a entrar en ese `if`, por lo que deberías cambiarlo a la siguiente manera:

```
if ($contrasena === $contrasena2 && strlen($contrasena) >= 8) //mayor o igual a 8
```

Un saludo.